Warning banner in all TeamsApp tab
I am writing to you as in the company we are experiencing an anomaly in the use of teamsapp exploiting tabs, for some days a red warning banner appears without text, this happens on any app whether proprietary or not. It also happens on both desktop client and web client.
Warning banner 1
Warning banner 2
Exploring the developer console of Chrome I noticed that it happens there is a message saying 'failed reason: AppInitTimeout', this happens on all installed apps that have tabs, whether frontend is available or not and even on apps that do not have a bot but only static frontend. How is this possible?
App init timeout error
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you

This is not a Microsoft support forum.

Sometimes we see this banner while adding tab to a channel but not in already added tabs. We will check internally and get back to you - https://i.sstatic.net/3b4pc5lD.png

Is there a solution available for this issue yet? @Meghana-MSFT

@Matteo Vailati

We see this issue very intermittently and that too while adding the tab. Could you please share a sample app package where this banner is showing up every time. Please share the app package at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com. As an initial analysis team said that Teams renders this banner when we do not initialize the Teams SDK. To investigate further we would need an app package with consistent repro. Thank you.

Engineering team has confirmed that now it is mandatory to initialise SDK for static tabs as well. Within your content page, add a reference to Microsoft Teams JavaScript client library using script tags. After your page loads, make a call to app.initialize(), or else your page isn't displayed. we display a banner instead of hiding the app because we didn't want to prevent customers from using these apps.

I have had this problem earlier and managed to solve it. What I have done is simply just put this in the homepage(first page the app is rendering) in my blazor project
`@inject TeamsUserCredential teamsUserCredential
@inject MicrosoftTeams MicrosoftTeams
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
if (firstRender)
{
var isInTeams = await MicrosoftTeams.IsInTeams();
if (isInTeams)
{
UserInfo user = await teamsUserCredential.GetUserInfoAsync();
}
StateHasChanged();
}
}`.
Maybe the code have tried to connect to Teams by this before the timeout, so that the error disappeared? But it works for me.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
