MS Teams - There was a problem reaching this app While loading custom App

I am integrating my Azure web app into Teams using the Teams Developer Portal. The app works fine, but I see the mentioned error at the top of the page after some time. Could you help me understand the possible cause of this issue and provide a solution?

Please add more details about the issue.

Similar issue was posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79042899/warning-banner-in-all-teamsapp-tab.
Engineering team has confirmed that now it is mandatory to initialise SDK for static tabs as well. Within your content page, add a reference to Microsoft Teams JavaScript client library using script tags. After your page loads, make a call to app.initialize(), or else your page isn't displayed. we display a banner instead of hiding the app because we didn't want to prevent customers from using these apps.

If you are adding a static page, then add this in your code, and the error will go away:
await microsoftTeams.app.initialize();

I was going through the same error, and it is fixed with this. Don’t forget to include this also:
https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.30.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js


This solution did not resolve my issue.
